# Why does Git convert CRLF to LF on Linux?

Tags: linux, git, line-endings

I have some shell scripts that need to have LF line endings (I'm on Ubuntu 14.04). Since this is a cross-platform open source project, a `.gitattributes` file is used to make line endings work 'automatically'. Unfortunately, they don't.

```
$ cat .gitattributes
# automatically normalize line endings
* text=auto
```

I have the following file on my file system:

```
$ file extract.sh 
extract.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminators
```

If I now process it using `dos2unix`, it shows correctly as LF terminated.

```
$ file extract.sh 
extract.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

Also, `git` shows it as modified:

```
$ git status
[..]
Changes not staged for commit:
[..]

    modified:   extract.sh
```

Now I add it to the index:

```
$ git add extract.sh 
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in extract.sh.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

But a new `git status` shows this:

```
$ git status .
[..]

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

And `file` shows it as unchanged:

```
$ file extract.sh 
extract.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

However, if I remove it and check it out again:

```
$ rm extract.sh 
$ git checkout extract.sh
$ file extract.sh 
extract.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminators
$ git status .
[..]

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Even removing it from the cache doesn't help:

```
$ git rm --cached extract.sh
$ git reset --hard
$ file extract.sh 
extract.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminators
```

The $100 question is: how do I get git to give me an LF terminated file?

Comment: Also see [this](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

> *If you’re on a Linux or Mac system that uses LF line endings, then you*
>   *don’t want Git to automatically convert them when you check out files;*
>   *however, if a file with CRLF endings accidentally gets introduced,*
>   *then you may want Git to fix it. You can tell Git to convert CRLF to*
>   *LF on commit but not the other way around by setting core.autocrlf to*
>   *input:*

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```